# About Intent requestCode, Android

Tags: android

Why my `toast` message is showing? My `CEVAP_SORGULA` variable equals 322, but my intents request code is 332

```
private final static int CEVAP_SORGULA = 322;
public void degistirActivity(final View view){
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,veriTopla.class),332);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CEVAP_SORGULA ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cevabin: " + data.getExtras().getInt("Cevap"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,veriTopla.class),332);

Comment: I see clearly a type error between the CEVAP_SORGULA and the value passed via startActivityForResult...

Comment: What is data.getExtras().getInt("Cevap"), I mean where "Cevap" key is declared? in your verTopla activity I suppose

Answer (score 3):

I see clearly a type error between the `CEVAP_SORGULA` and the value passed via `startActivityForResult`. To fix it provide the variable instead of the hardcoded **WRONG** value.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,veriTopla.class),CEVAP_SORGULA);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 332);
```

DEFAULT METHOD

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

SEE THIS EXAMPLE FROM ANDROID DEVELOPER SITE, MAKE YOU HELP

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     ...

     static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

     protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
             // When the user center presses, let them pick a contact.
             startActivityForResult(
                 new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                 new Uri("content://contacts")),
                 PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
            return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
             Intent data) {
         if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 // A contact was picked.  Here we will just display it
                 // to the user.
                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data));
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks again. Now requestCode == CEVAP_SORGULA is working again but requestCode == 332 isn't working.

Comment: CEVAP_SORGULA  and 332  are the same?

Comment: you first check requestCode  with constant valu then check resultCode == RESULT_OK

Comment: my fold my fold, so sorry Mohammod I couldn't answer you. I did a stupid mistake. I had two button, and I wrote codes for wrong button. I'm so sorry.